# Moving axes in animation

Tags: plotting, graphics, animation

I'm having trouble creating a smooth animation which zooms in on a plot while the axes stay fixed.  The application I have in mind is quite complicated, but the issue already arises in the following simplified version:

```
Table[Plot[x + 1/6, {x, 1/3 - epsilon, 1/3 + epsilon}, PlotRange -> {1/2 - epsilon, 1/2 + epsilon}, AxesOrigin -> {1/3, 1/2}, Ticks -> False], {epsilon, 3/4, 1/10, -.01}]
```

The resulting animation stays fixed as expected for the initial frames, then the axes drift right, then they pop back to the center and stay fixed for the rest of the animation:

[image: Drifting axes]

I'm at a loss for what to try, so any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:  It appears this might be some kind of bug with Mathematica 10.0, it doesn't appear to be reproduceable in some older and newer versions.

Comment: Add options `ImagePadding -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None` to `Plot`

Comment: @Edmund  I think you should write this as an answer, rather than a comment. +1

Comment: With Edmunds hint you can try: `Manipulate[Plot[x + 1/6, {x, 1/3 - epsilon, 1/3 + epsilon}, PlotRange -> {1/2 - epsilon, 1/2 + epsilon}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {1/3, 1/2}, PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None], {epsilon, 3/4, 1/10, -.01}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the `ImagePadding` and `PlotRangePadding` options of `Plot` to control the *extra automatically calculated spacings* that are applied.

```
plots =
  Table[
   Plot[x + 1/6, {x, 1/3 - epsilon, 1/3 + epsilon},
    PlotRange -> {1/2 - epsilon, 1/2 + epsilon},
    AxesOrigin -> {1/3, 1/2},
    ImagePadding -> None,
    PlotRangePadding -> None
    ],
   {epsilon, 3/4, 1/10, -.01}];
ListAnimate[plots]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  For some reason when I tried my original code at home (On Mathematica 9.0) it worked just fine.  I'll have to try your solution at work (Mathematica 11.something) to see if it fixes the issue.  I had played around with some of the padding options but they didn't seem to help.

Comment: @JackHuizenga This answer is on version 11.2, if that helps.

Comment: Turns out my version at work is 10.0, and the above code produces the same output (+tick marks) as the original example I provided.  Guess that's a reason to update to the latest version.  Thanks!